# JAX-WS client, incorrect soap request - The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed

Tags: soap, jaxb, jax-ws, webservice-client, wsimport

I have generated a web service client using wsimport command line (JAX-WS) and generated Java objects using JAXB and separate XSD files.

But when I try to request, it gives following error from server side.

> *SAXException, cause: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.*

So I checked my soap request with a sample working soap message. Then I realized that there is a different between these two messages.

**1. Sample working message.**

> ```
> <m:getMyDetail xmlns:m="http://axis.frontend.hi.example.net"> 
> <MyDetailRQ xmlns="http://www.example.net/schemas/1005/06/messages" 
> xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
> xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.net/1005/06/messages ../xsd/MyDetailRQ.xsd" 
> version="2013/12">
> ```

**2. Web service client generated soap message.**

> ```
> <ns3:getMyDetail xmlns:ns3="http://axis.frontend.hi.example.net" xmlns="http://www.  
> example.net/schemas/1005/06/messages" xmlns:ns2="http://www. example.net/wsdl/1005/06"  
> xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="MyDetailRQ">
> ```

As you can see, above expected **MyDetailRQ** wrapper tag element is missing but it generated as **xsi:type="MyDetailRQ" attribute.**

I’m not sure why this happen and how to fix this through my client project configurations.

Appreciate your help and advice.

Thanks

**- Relevant WSDL part**

```
<wsdl:types>
    <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://axis.frontend.h1.example.com">
        <element name="getMyDetail" type="xsd:anyType"/>
    </schema>
    <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.example.com/wsdl/2005/06">
        <element name="getMyDetailReturn" type="xsd:anyType"/>
    </schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="getMyDetailRequest">
    <wsdl:part element="tns1:getMyDetail" name="part"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="getMyDetailResponse">
    <wsdl:part element="impl:getMyDetailReturn" name="getMyDetailReturn"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="MyService">
    <wsdl:operation name="getMyDetail">
        <wsdl:input message="impl:getMyDetailRequest" name="getMyDetailRequest"/>
        <wsdl:output message="impl:getMyDetailResponse" name="getMyDetailResponse"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="MyServiceSoapBinding" type="impl:MyService">
    <wsdl:operation name="getMyDetail">
        <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction=""/>
        <wsdl:input name="getMyDetailRequest">
            <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output name="getMyDetailResponse">
            <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="MyServiceService">
    <wsdl:port binding="impl:MyServiceSoapBinding" name="MyService">
        <wsdlsoap:address location="http://interface.example.com/xmls/ws/MyService"/>
    </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

**- Relevant XSD part**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://www.example.net/schemas/1005/06/messages" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.example.net/schemas/1005/06/messages" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:include schemaLocation="MyCommonTypes.xsd"/>
    <xs:element name="MyDetailRQ">
```

**- Relevant Java Object**

> ```
> @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
> @XmlType(name = "MyDetailRQ", propOrder = {
>     "myCode"
> })
> @XmlRootElement(name = "MyDetailRQ")
> public class MyDetailRQ
>     extends MainRequest
> {
> }
> ```

**- web service client - service interface (Updated on 17-Oct-2014)**

```
    @WebService(name = "MyService", targetNamespace = "http://www.example.net/wsdl/1005/06")
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)
@XmlSeeAlso({
    com.myp.hi.frontend.axis.ObjectFactory.class,
        com.myp.ObjectFactory.class
})
public interface MyService {
    /**
         * 
         * @param part
         * @return
         *     returns java.lang.Object
         */
        @WebMethod
        @WebResult(name = "getMyDetailReturn", targetNamespace = "http://www.example.net/wsdl/1005/06", partName = "getMyDetailReturn")
        public Object getMyDetail(
            @WebParam(name = "getMyDetail", targetNamespace = "http://axis.frontend.hi.example.net", partName = "part")
            Object part);

}
```

**- ObjectFactory class (Updated on 17-Oct-2014)**

```
@XmlRegistry
public class ObjectFactory {

    private final static QName _GetMyDetail_QNAME = new QName("http://axis.frontend.hi.example.net", "getMyDetail");


    public ObjectFactory() {
    }

    @XmlElementDecl(namespace = "http://axis.frontend.hi.example.net", name = "getMyDetail")
            public JAXBElement<Object> createGetMyDetail(Object value) {
            return new JAXBElement<Object>(_GetMyDetail_QNAME, Object.class, null, value);
    }


 }
```

**-MyServiceService class (Updated on 17-Oct-2014)**

```
@WebServiceClient(name = "MyServiceService", targetNamespace = "http://www.example.net/wsdl/1005/06", wsdlLocation = "http://interface.example.com/xmls/ws/MyService?wsdl")
@GZIP
public class MyServiceService
    extends Service
{

    private final static URL MYSERVICESERVICE_WSDL_LOCATION;
    private final static WebServiceException MYSERVICESERVICE_EXCEPTION;
    private final static QName MYSERVICESERVICE_QNAME = new QName("http://www.example.net/wsdl/1005/06", "MyServiceService");

    static {
        URL url = null;
        WebServiceException e = null;
        try {
            url = new URL("http://interface.example.com/xmls/ws/MyService?wsdl");
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            e = new WebServiceException(ex);
        }
        MYSERVICESERVICE_WSDL_LOCATION = url;
        MYSERVICESERVICE_EXCEPTION = e;
    }

 @WebEndpoint(name = "MyService")
    public MyService getMyService() {

        MyService port = super.getPort(new QName("http://www.example.net/wsdl/1005/06", "MyService"), MyService.class);
        return port;
    }

 private static URL __getWsdlLocation() {
        if (MYSERVICESERVICE_EXCEPTION!= null) {
            throw MYSERVICESERVICE_EXCEPTION;
        }
        return MYSERVICESERVICE_WSDL_LOCATION;
    }


}
```

**- My Test class (Updated on 17-Oct-2014)**

```
MyService myService = new MyServiceService().getMyService();

MyDetailRQ myDetailRQ = new MyDetailRQ();


myDetailRQ.setCredentials(credentials);
myDetailRQ.setLanguage("ENG");
myDetailRQ.setMyCode("52319");

MyDetailRS myDetailRS = (MyDetailRS) myService.getMyDetail(myService);
```

Comment: How do you construct the `getMyDetail` instance?

Comment: I hope you are taking about ObjectFactory, any way I have updated issue with all information that I have including test class.
Thanks for checking.

Comment: When set blank to @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {"hotelCode"}) in MyDetailRQ I'm getting the following error. 'org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Marshalling Error: Instance of "com.myp.hi.dataobject.MyDetailRQ" is substituting "java.lang.Object", but "com.mpy.hi.dataobject.MyDetailRQ" is bound to an anonymous type.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution, but not sure whether perfect one.

What I have done is; pass a XML String to service and get response as a String from service.
Then manually do marshalling and un- marshalling.

See the example below.

```
MyService myService = new MyServiceService().getMyService();

MyDetailRQ myDetailRQ = new MyDetailRQ();


myDetailRQ.setCredentials(credentials);
myDetailRQ.setLanguage("ENG");
myDetailRQ.setMyCode("52319");

String requestStr = getStringFromJaxb(myDetailRQ.class, myDetailRQ);

String responseStr = (String) myService.getMyDetail(requestStr);

MyDetailRS myDetailRS = (MyDetailRS) getJaxbFromString(MyDetailRS.class, responseStr);




private static Object getJaxbFromString(Class<?> clazz, String xmlString) {
        StringReader input = null;
        Object o = null;
        try {
            input = new StringReader(xmlString);
            JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(clazz);
            Unmarshaller um = context.createUnmarshaller();
            o = um.unmarshal(input);
            if (o instanceof JAXBElement)
                o = ((JAXBElement<?>) o).getValue();
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (input != null)
                input.close();
        }
        return o;
    }



/**
     * Helper method to get xml string from JAXB Object.
     * @param clazz
     * @param o
     * @return
     */
    private static String getStringFromJaxb(Class<?> clazz, Object o) {
        String theXML = "";
        try {
            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
            JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(clazz);
            Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
            m.setProperty("com.sun.xml.bind.xmlDeclaration", Boolean.FALSE);
            m.marshal(o, writer);

            // output string to console
            theXML = writer.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return theXML;
    }
```